# Socket programming:Assign name to port number

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

Is it possible to assign name to port number

like

localhost:8888 as localhost:xyz

localhost:9000 as localhost:abc

I want to hide port number from client side while giving them link

I have video streaming server (different streaming on different port) ...want to hide port number because any one can change port and will be able to see other stream

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. The way TCP/IP works requires both ends to know the number of the port, just like they both have to know each other's IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the port numbers(source and destination port numbers) to the transportlayer.
TCP uses the concept of Port `multiplexing` i.e to use the different port numbers for different applications. Also if you check the TCP header, there are fields for source and destination port.

So you cannot change anything in the `transport` layer packet or TCP packet. But you always have control on the `application` layer, so you can create a mapping of port and names in your application and can use it. You can use data structure such as `Map` to store the port number and name mapping. This will allow you to use the port names in your application logic. But while sending the packet over the socket or to the TCP layer, make sure that you pass the port numbers instead of name.